# Frigidaire Electric Range trips arc-fault circuit breaker in another room

Tags: electrical-panel

I have a problem that occurs intermittently in several different apartment units.  Kitchen has Frigidaire Electric Range.  Living room (LR) and bedroom (BR) have 15 Amp AFCI circuit breakers that control ceiling lights in the kitchen and LR & outlets in LR.

At times when one or more burners are in use on the range, the AFCI that controls Ceiling Lights in LR & Kitchen and outlets in LR will trip.  I am changing out the 15 Amp AFCI because I don't see anything wrong.  It doesn't do it all the time and it has done it in at least 5 different apartments.

All apartments are wired the same & all have the same range.  What the heck is causing this?

Comment: Does the range turn off when the breaker trips?

Comment: This is a question for a qualified professional, not a home improvement DIYer. It sounds like there's a weakness in the entire service related to the neutral.

Comment: What make and model are these AFCIs?

Comment: A Google search shows this is not a unique problem. I have not seen a definitive resolution in any case, but musings suspect a problem in the neutral connection in the panel as isherwood has already commented. See http://forums.mikeholt.com/showthread.php?t=134732

Comment: AFCI's have significant design flaws for use with electronic controlled circuits. They can not tell the difference from an arc and a variable light control with a heavy load. Also with motor controls that are variable speed same issue. Induction cook units there can be kick back on the line when the unit is cycling causing other circuits to see the spikes. Line suppression at the range may solve the problems you are seeing. These are MOV  devices mounted close to the source of the electrical noise. ( if mounted at the panel the suppressor may work but I had to mount at the outlet last year).

Comment: AFCI's are Siemens units 15 Amp.  When the AFCI trips it does not affect the stove breaker.

Answer (score 1):

The surface burner controllers on electric ranges work by making and breaking the circuit to the heating element. I don't know the frequency at which this occurs, but this mode of operation would appear to have the potential to trigger an arc fault breaker or receptacle. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_regulator

Therefore, some ranges might trip some AFCI breakers or receptacles. Is AFCI protection appropriate for a kitchen? I thought AFCI was for bedrooms.

Frigidaire is a name brand of range so I would first suspect the AFCI receptacle or breaker. What is the type (receptacle or breaker) and brand of AFCI device you have in the kitchen circuits of these apartments?

Comment: How many years have these Frigidaire ranges been in service? These surface burner controllers do wear out over long use. In my GE electric range (25 years in service) all four surface burner controllers have lost the lower end. That is, there is absolutely no heating when they are set to warm or a little above warm. The one burner we use the most (to boil water) has lost 1/4 of the range on the low end. Our kitchen is not AFCI protected. OK, I admit it, we have no AFCI protection anywhere in the 47-year-old house.

Answer (score 1):

Is it really the electric range causing the problem or the high load or the refrigerator with the higher loads?

Try a hair dryer on high say a 1900 watt unit - cycle the thing on and off. 
No tripping ...
With either you Hair Dryer running and/or your range burners , open the refrigerator door and wait until the refrigerator cycles on - then if it trips .. you will need to put the refrigerator on a separate circuit - that is the problem.

AFCI's when they first came out were a pain in the butt, I have heard that some AFCI's trip when simply plugging in a device that is in the switched on position.

My question is how are the circuits fed - you state Ceiling Lights in LR & Kitchen and outlets in LR. AFCI is usually on the outlets, aside form that is it one AFCI or two or three how is it wired can make a difference (for example a refrigerator is not usually connected to an AFCI - the motor cycling can trip it (and this might be your problem the burners mean nothing - the refrigerator kicks on while the burners are running and BAM. - you might also have a wiring issue - perhaps the range is not wired appropriately. You have not provided enough details to help you.

1: 4 Wire or 3 Wire Range.
2: AFCI - what is on AFCI - for example in the list you provided LR, BR, KI how many AFCI breakers and to what do they connect lights, outlets, both , refrigerator etc...

Comment: AFCI Brkrs are siemens 15 Amp.  Brkrs are NOT wired to any kitchen outlet.  Refrigerator is NOT on AFCI and service to Refrigerator is never interrupted.  Service to Range is not interrupted when lighting and outlet circuits are interrupted (AFCI circuits)

Comment: @JimSchee I think in this instance you might need to change the breakers and use a different manufacturer, not the best thing from what I understand about panels they can be manufacturer specific to a point and so it is not typically recommended, I am not sure if that is to sell more CB's for their panels or if there is truly a good reason. Did flipping the hair dryer on/off several times while the hair dryer was on high get them to kick out ?  If the hair dryer is on a separate outlet system I would be curious. What voltage do you measure at the outlets that are on AFCI , 120 ? or 110? .