# Electrical issues

Tags: circuit-breaker

I am a maintenance tech in an apartment complex.  I have a perplexing issue.  We have 2 or 3 apartments that, when the electric range burners are in use ( sometimes 1 burner - sometimes 2) the 15 Amp AFCI for the living room ceiling light and outlets and kitchen ceiling light will trip.   Not every time the stove is in use only once in a while.

Load on the breaker that trips is usually a TV the two ceiling lights and maybe an oxygen generator.  The AFCI never trips unless the burners on the range are on and not all the time then.

I have changed a couple of AFCI breakers out because they seem a little flaky and it seems to have solved the issue.   What is it about AFCI breakers that would make them do this?

Comment: Are you in a jurisdiction where you are legally permitted to do this work? (I get that you might be trying to do your best for your employer, but there are times where the risk to human life demands a professional get involved. If for no other reason than for the sake of your conscience.)

Comment: This question [seems familiar](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/109181/frigidaire-electric-range-trips-arc-fault-circuit-breaker-in-another-room).

Comment: I am wondering if the range and lighting branch circuits are run parallel in close proximity since multiple cases. Some ranges use electronic control to adjust the power. This could be creating harmonics that are being induced onto the lighting circuit. Even make and break controls can cause this adding a MOV protection device may eliminate the problem. This would be cheaper than having the panels monitored for several fault cycles.

Comment: I've seen cases where incorrect breakers cause the buss bar to heat and trip adjacent breakers. And this is a dup question.

Answer (score 0):

**AFCI Operation**

AFCI outlets (combination types, at least) detect three types of faults: Series Arcing (along any one wire if it arcs), Ground Arcing, and Neutral Arcing. If the range works in such a way that it creates electrical noise similar to arcing, it will cause the AFCI to trip.

**An Electric Range on a 15A Breaker?**

Are you sure the electric range is on a 15A breaker? If that's the case, it will probably trip from overcurrent regularly, AFCI excluded. I'd see about moving the range to a dedicated circuit.

**Oxygen Generator???**

I can't imagine why you'd have something like that unless it was some type of medical equipment. If it is medical equipment ***STOP IMMEDIATELY*** and have a licensed professional complete all the work. You really don't want to mess with medical equipment.

Comment: I understood the question to mean that when the electric range was in use, the breaker **for another circuit** would trip. Presumably the range is on a dedicated breaker of a higher capacity.

Comment: You may be correct. As @EdBeal pointed out in a different comment, it's possible that the range circuit oscillations induce harmonics in nearby circuitry. Without that, it would be strange to see different circuits behave like this.